# Switch to local database

Tags: c#, javascript, sql, database, visual-studio

I was suggested to keep it to one question at the time so here it is.

I am having a local copy of a website-project I was thrown into with very bad documentation and now I have to develop a few things for it. What I want to do is use the local database and not the one on the server to be sure that I can test things properly. I have the website error-free and can run it but the database needs to get redirected and I am not sure exactly what I should change it to.

```
<connectionStrings> 
<!--add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=11.11.111.11;
    DATABASE=websitename;USER ID=websitename;PASSWORD=xxxxxx;PORT=1234"/-->
<add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=localhost;
    DATABASE=websitename;USER ID=username;PASSWORD=xxxxxxx;PORT=1234"/>
```

I assume I should change "DATA SOURCE=11.11.111.11;" to something like "DATA SOURCE=\databasename.sql" or something like that.

Also...it appears that every time I try to connect the database in one way or another it doesn't want a .sql file but a .mdf file instead. But on the server-side it doesn't seem to care.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to set up a web server for your local copy, a database server or an ODBC driver plus file (Access DB, maybe) with your local database, then you'll be able to test your project.

Comment: Have you tried 
`DATA SOURCE=.;`
this???

Answer (score 0):

the correct solution depends on the rdbms you are using (are you using a rdbms? do you have mysql/sqlserver/postgre installed?). if on the production web server you have a rdbms you have to install that rdbms on your machine (or on a test server) also and create a test database. maybe a test database on production server would fit but it's up to you.

if you have a file instead (eg: access mdb) just copy that file locally and modify the connection string accordingly.

for hints on connection strings you can have a look at [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) where a wide list of examples for various databases is present.